What is causing the leak inside my furnace?
What could be causing the leak in this area? I assume it's a slow leak since I never noticed it until i opened the panel. Both the A/C and heating are working.


Condensate from the ac or, if very high efficiency furnace, condensate from exhaust

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact why is the condensate from the A/C going into the furnace?

is this a water heater

@Traveler No. It's a furnace.

@MethodicalMind why is the condensate from the A/C going into the furnace? ... that is what you have to determine and remedy

if it is a furnace only, there is no AC near it
